# Prevent CTRL + F12 form triggering program to reads texts

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

When my caret is inside text and I press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>**, Windows reads that text.

How can I disable this functionality?

Comment: What do you expect/want to happen when you press *Ctrl+F12*?

Comment: Normally nothing. I use another program. It uses Ctrl+F12 to make some action. So these shorcuts conflict. I need to remove this conflict.

Comment: What does "windows reads that text" mean?

Comment: I meaned "Text-to-Speech".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accidentially i found the answer.
Lingoes software was triggering Ctrl+F12 and played Text-to-Speech.